# Core usage in scala actor model

Tags: performance, scala, actor, cpu-time

I just started learning scala. Is there any way to find CPU time and real time and the cores used by the program when using actor model??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a [profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762/please-recommend-a-java-profiler) such as [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/)  or more adhoc and pleasant solution: [Typesafe console](http://typesafe.com/products/console).

Answer (score 0):

how about using the unix system time function ?

> time scalac HelloWorld.scala

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in Linux (specifically here I'm describing Ubuntu) `mpstat` is a useful program.

You can install it using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install sysstat
```

Once installed you can run a bash script to record CPU info. In this case I'm logging 10 times a second. This will block until you press Control-C to kill the logging. (Also, consider removing the `sleep 0.1;` for better data.)

```
while x=0; do mpstat -P ALL >> cpu_log.txt; sleep 0.1; done
```

In another terminal you can fire off your program (or ANY program) and see track the performance data. The output looks like this:

```
03:21:08 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
03:21:08 PM  all    0.37    0.00    0.33    0.50    0.00    0.02    0.00    0.00   98.78
03:21:08 PM    0    0.51    0.00    0.45    0.57    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00   98.43
03:21:08 PM    1    0.29    0.00    0.26    0.45    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00   99.00
```